# Bluetooth microphone hangs/crashes audio services after Win11 upgrade

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microphone, windows-11

Since upgrading to 10.0.22000 Build 22000 attempting to use the microphone on my bluetooth headset reliably crashes audio on my Dell XPS 15 7590 laptop.

The headset is a Sony WH-CH700N.

**Observed Symptoms**

- Whichever app attempts to interact with the microphone will hang. All other apps will lose audio output.
- Eventually the hanging app will recover - or I will kill it.
- Any other app or program that attempt to play audio will hang.
- Eventually Windows Audio Service will be killed (during this time nothing plays audio of course)
- Windows automatically restarts audio service as per service recovery settings.
- Audio works perfectly again... until the next time something tries to use the mic
- WER will log something like:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: AppHangXProcB1
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: svchost.exe_Audiosrv
P2: 10.0.22000.1
P3: 5155ab18
P4: 1fb8
P5: 64
P6: audiodg.exe
P7: 10.0.22000.100
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Connect headset.
2. Set default input device to be the WH-CH700N
3. Do any of the following: (and certainly more I haven't tried)

- Open Google Meet in any browser
- Connect to Zoom with laptop audio
- Join a Slack call or "Huddle"
- Toggle the "allow exclusive mode" option in device settings.

**Things that don't crash audio**

- Just playing audio through the headset irrespective of the default input device.
- Opening Meet or a Slack call while the laptop mic is the default device.
- Performing microphone test through Windows Settings irrespective of the default device.
- Using the built-in "Audio Recorder" windows app irrespective of audio device selected
- Visiting https://mictests.com/ with laptop mic selected and then changing the microphone to use the headset mic.

**Things I have tried (without success)**

- Disabling "allow exclusive mode" on the headset
- Removing and re-pairing with the headset
- Removing the bluetooth device from device manager and letting Windows reinstall it
- Removing all audio devices (and drivers) from device manager and letting windows re-install it.
- Updating all drivers (including Realtek audio) to latest version
- Throwing the bluetooth headset at the wall. (It did make me feel better).

I don't have any other external input device I can test with.

Would appreciate any help troubleshooting! Hoping I can find a way through that won't require rolling back, reinstalling or buying another headset.

Comment: Windows 11 is still pre-release (and will bee for a while yet). You can either wait (November) to see if there is a fix, or roll back to Windows 10 while you can. Bluetooth is working fine on my X230 machine with Windows 11 so it is a compatibility issue.

Comment: It's not clear by the information provided what BT device you actually have.  Worth pointing out that Intel updated and validated their BT drivers for Windows 11.  [Here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18649/646235/intel-wireless-bluetooth-for-windows-10.html) is that driver.

Comment: It's a Sony headset model WH-CH700N - unsure what extra information I could add about the device to help clarify. I updated the Intel drivers - thank you for that tip! - unfortunately it didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my Dell XPS 13 when I used Microsoft Teams with my Bluetooth headset (JBL Live 660NC after sending back my FreshnRebel Code ANC for the same problem). I have solved it by

1. Going to the sound settings
2. Clicking on the headphone in the list of "output" devices (not the headset in the list of "input" devices)
3. Change "Audio enhancements" drop-down to "Off".

Now the audio service doesn't hang any more. When the microphone of the headphone is in use, the output sound (music) is in mono.
Alternatively you can combine the microphone of your laptop with the output of the headphones. Which also solves the problem in a way.

Comment: I had the EXACT same problem on a Dell XPS 13, except with a "Scoundcore  Liberty Air 2 Pro" — This solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue since build 22000.51 till current build in my PC 22000.132.

My headphone is JBL TUNE 500BT

And I found this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fix-for-bluetooth-headphones-or-speaker-using/7023c43b-c001-42e9-9ec9-95a8f96a4b4c.

For using communication application (Microsoft Teams, Skype, Zoom...), turn off **Audio Sink** only. Keep **Hands-free Telephony** and other service like Remote Control... Your Bluetooth device will connect as voice (Settings > Bluetooth & devices > Devices -> Audio) Windows 11 didn't crash/hang any more.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I tried this out and noticed disabling "hands free technology" stopped the headset from acting as a microphone. While doing this does ensure my default mic doesn't inadvertently revert back to using the the headset - it also didn't resolve the issue. But I appreciate the information, thanks!

Comment: No worries, when using communication application I disable Audio Sink, enable Hands-free Telephony. When listen to music, I disable Hands-free Telephony and enable Audio Sink.